# Can I set suffix in logging config for TimedRotatingFileHandler

Tags: python, logging

Can I set suffix in logging config for `TimedRotatingFileHandler`?

Like this :

```
[handler_infohand]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=fmt
suffix="%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
args=('logtailer.log','S', 5, 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible for fileConfig().
As of 2023 documentation says:

> **Note** The fileConfig() API is older than the dictConfig() API and does not provide functionality to cover certain aspects of logging.

So, usage of dictConfig() will give you following approach when dictionary readed from yaml file:

```
  infohand:
    class: 'logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler'
    level: 'INFO'
    formatter: 'fmt'
    when: 'midnight'
    backupCount: 7
    filename: 'example.log'
    '.':
      suffix: '%Y%m%d'
```

The documentation describes this feature as follows:

> You can also specify a special key '.' whose value is a dictionary is a mapping of attribute names to values. If found, the specified attributes will be set on the user-defined object before it is returned.